# How to use variables in option parameters for a plugin (like fullpage.js)?

Tags: jquery, variables, plugins, fullpage.js

I've been looking for hours to find the answer of my problem, but could'nt find anything usefull.

I'm using the fullpage.js plugin, one of the various option is "anchors". I'd like to use this one but I'll never know the link's names that I've to put in it. They can change in number and names aswell.

So I store all the names I need in a array, then I change this array into a string to use it in the anchors option.

```
var data_anchors = $('.elements').map(function(){
        return $(this).data('menuanchor');
        }).get(),
        anchors_array = [];
$.each(data_anchors, function(id,val) {                    
     var str = "'" + val + "'";
     anchors_array.push(str);
});

var anchors_var = anchors_array.join(", ");
```

I've tested the output with `alert()` and it is perfect, but the plugin/jquery doesn't recognize it, and throw an error :

```
$(".slide").fullpage({
  // //Navigation
  anchors:[anchors_str],
.....
```

> **Error :**
>   Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #'link_name1', 'link_name2', 'link_name3'

If write all the link's names manually it works.

Where is the catch? How to make it work?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why do you turn it into a string? can't you just say anchors:anchors_array ?

Comment: Yes but `data_anchors` not `anchors_array`.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, but none of your solutions are working. @Jeremy your solution give the same error as mine.

Comment: @Roamer your solution gives no error but it bugs aswell. it changes my first section data-anchor value and this is not good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fullpage` expects an array of strings, not an array with one concatenated string.

```
$(".slide").fullpage({
    // //Navigation
    anchors: $('.elements').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('menuanchor');
    }).get(),
    .....
});
```

Comment: @Roamer-1988 Lovely!!! It works as expected! How do you know that `FullPage` needs array of string and not an array with one concatenated string? which is not what i was trying to do, I was trying to get a simple string, btw ;)

Comment: I consulted the documentation!